# Best practice to check for null in LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

Assuming I have a LINQ query as such ...

```
var selectedUser = myDb.Users.Where<User>(u => u.Email == email).Single<User>();
```

What is the best way to see if I received a result back? Do I just check if `selectedUser != null`

```
if (selectedUser != null)
{
  // OK, not null so go ahead and do stuff
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with your attempted solution?  In what way is it failing to solve your problem?

Comment: `Single<T>()` will helpfully throw an exception if there isn't exactly one of them. `SingleOrDefault<T>()` will do what @Servy says it does.

Comment: Side note: assuming `myDb.Users` is an `IEnumerable<User>`, you don't need `<User>` on the Where or Single.

Comment: @EdPlunkett `SingleOrDefault` will return the default value if there are exactly zero items, and throw if there is more than one item.

Comment: @gunr2171 - `myDb.Users` is a `System.Data.Linq.Table<User>` that is why I felt I needed to use `<User>`. Am I incorrect in this?

Comment: @webworm please consider providing sample that actually can return null from the query... with `Single` you'll never get to null check with null.

Comment: @webworm Yes, you are incorrect in that.

Comment: Is it considered better to use `.Single()` if there is a chance of no match and then handle the exception? As opposed to using `.SingleOrDefault()` and checking for `null`?

Comment: @webworm I would think try/catch has a higher overhead than just doing `FirstOrDefault()`.  Remember if you use `SingleOrDefault()` you run the risk of getting an exception if there are more than one element.  With `FirstOrDefault()` you do not have that same problem.

Comment: @maccettura That's assuming it's actually acceptable for there to be multiple matches.  There might not be.

Comment: @Servy Good point

Comment: @Servy - There should not be, however, using `SingleOrDefault()` as @maccettura mentioned, I should be able to catch the fact that there is one, if there is. Thank you both!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Single()` will throw an exception if there are no matches.

`SingleOrDefault()` will return a single element, or a default value.  **However it will throw exception if there are more than one element in the sequence**.

If you are ok with just taking the first element **if** there happens to be more than use `FirstOrDefault()` for this:

```
var selectedUser = myDb.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == email);
```

Then just check if it is null like normal:

```
if (selectedUser != null)
{
    // OK, not null so go ahead and do stuff
}
```

**Side Note** In either case you shouldn't need your explicit `<T>` definitions.  Also the `Where()` clause is redundant, you can pass your lambda in `FirstOrDefault()`, `Single()`, `SingleOrDefault()`, etc.

Comment: @gunr2171 indicated the same thing you did. That <User> was not necessary. The type of `myDb.Users` is `System.Data.Linq.Table<User>`. For this reason, I thought I needed to use explicit `<T>`. Am I incorrect on this assumption?

Comment: @webworm indeed, the compiler will infer the `<T>` whenever it can and only complain that you haven't been explicit if it cannot work out the types itself.

Answer (score -1):

.Single will throw an exception if there isn't a matching item. Instead use SingleOrDefault and check for null.